# How to write Notebook to Databricks using API?

Tags: databricks, databricks-rest-api

I am able to write data files to Databricks using the APIs documented here:

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/index.html

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs.html

I have several Notebooks I would like to write to a Databricks instance.  I'm not seeing how to do this in the API documentation.  Is there a way to write a Notebook to a Databricks instance using a Rest API?  Where is this documented?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Workspace API instead, specifically the [Import call](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import). For example, with curl (example from documentation):

```
curl -n -F path=/Users/user@example.com/project/ScalaExampleNotebook  \
  -F language=SCALA -F content=@example.scala \
  https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/workspace/import
```

If you don't use API directly, the better way would be to use [`workspace` subcommand of Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html) (`import` or `import_dir`), or use [Databricks Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/notebook)